# Python - Search and Replace in JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'd like to replace the displayName field in python:

```py
json = {
    "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema",
    "id": "743145",
    "self": "XXXXXXXXXXXX/api/2/issue/743145",
    "key": "TEST1234-1266",
    "fields": {
        "issuelinks": [],
        "assignee": {
            "self": "XXXXXXXXXXXX/api/2/user?username=XX.XX",
            "name": "ted.bundy@gmail.com",
            "key": "JIRAUSER22031",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "XXXXXXXXXXXXjira/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122",
                "24x24": "XXXXXXXXXXXXjira/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
                "16x16": "XXXXXXXXXXXXjira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10122",
                "32x32": "XXXXXXXXXXXXjira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10122"
            },
            "displayName": "ted.bundy@gmail.com",
            "active": true,
            "timeZone": "Europe/London"
        },
        "components": [{
            "self": "XXXXXXXXXXXX/api/2/component/23015",
            "id": "23015",
            "name": "AWS_EC2",
            "description": "AWS_EC2"
        }]
    }
}
```

The way it is done currently is by a search and replace from a csv file.

code:

```
import json
import csv
import os
import requests

site = "https://xxxx.com/xxxxxx/rest/api/2/search?xxxx=project=UKTEST"

url = requests.get(site, auth=auth, )
url_json = mtd_list.json()
url_str = json.dumps(mtd_json)

with open("names.csv","r+") as data:

    # csv file
    csvInput = csv.reader(data)

    # Search and replace
    for row in csvInput:
        replacerow = url_str.replace(row[0], (row[1]),)
        url_str= replacerow
```

csv file contains:

```
ted.bundy@gmail.com tbundy
```

How would I get the above to work but with the url_json?

Comment: there are multiple problems in your code snippet preventing to execute it. please provide an example that potential answerers can execute without any fix. It will help people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update json like this:

```
url_json["displayName"] = ""
```

Whats the rule for changing displayName? Its not clear in your question.

Comment: I forgot to add the name in there.  I have corrected it now.